# Copying background colors using .getBackgrounds() to a range

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm copying the background colors from a sheet into an array like this:

```
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Refresh');
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var sourceStatusColorValues = sheet.getRange(1,11,lastRow,1).getBackgrounds(); //background color from column K (11)
var sourceProjectIDValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Projects');
var targetProjectIDValues = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
```

Next I'm comparing the project ID from one sheet to the next and copying the background colors to an array so that I could use the `.setBackgrounds()` method to apply all the background colors in the right order.

```
//Compare the projectIDs for Target Sheet with the project IDs in Source Sheet.
//If match then add the background color to the colorValues array
var colorValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < targetProjectIDValues.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < sourceProjectIDValues.length; j++) {
    if (targetProjectIDValues[i] == sourceProjectIDValues[j]) { 
      colorValues[i] = sourceStatusColorValues[j];
      break;
      }
    }
  }

  targetSheet.getRange(1, 11, targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgrounds(colorValues);
```

The issue that I'm running into is that the values in copyValues array are all `null` and NOT the hexadecimal values of the background colors.

What am I missing? Could someone help? Appreciate it!!!

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function backgrounds(){
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sourceColors = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getBackgrounds();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  var targetColors = [];

  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var targetData = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++){
    if (sourceData[i][0] == targetData[i][0])
      targetColors.push([sourceColors[i][0]]);
    else
      targetColors.push(['#FFFFFF']);
  }
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow()).setBackgrounds(targetColors);
}
```

The problem you were having is that `getBackgrounds()` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)) and `getValues()` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)) both return 2D arrays, and you were treating them as 1D. I tested this code with a sheet with one column of values comparing them against a second sheet, it put the corresponding value of values that matched rows.

**UPDATE**

I modified the code to use `setBackgrounds()` instead, it should be much better for working with large data sets.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I just have one follow-up. I could certainly do it your way where I use a for loop and .setBackground() function to set the background color for each individual row. However, my original request was for setting the background colors for ALL rows simultaneously using .setBackrounds() function instead of individual row using setBackground(). Is there a way to use setBackgrounds() using the entire sourceColors array?

Comment: @cadbury4all Updated the code! it now uses `setBackgrounds()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated. Works like a charm. :-)

Comment: @cadbury4all I'm glad to hear that! Please consider marking the answer as accepted so the question is marked as solved.